# updating to angular 9 to 10 I get this issue

Tags: updating, angular10

While trying to update from ng9 to ng 10 the process stalls and doesn't move (see below):

```
Updating package.json with dependency @angular/router @ "10.1.4" (was "9.0.5")...
Updating package.json with dependency rxjs @ "6.6.3" (was "6.5.4")...
Updating package.json with dependency zone.js @ "0.10.3" (was "0.10.2")...
UPDATE package.json (1892 bytes)
- Installing packages...
```

Hangs for approx. 10 mins and then fails - but get E503, so thinking it's a proxy issue, will update on progress

Comment: Wait for a bit of time.

Comment: how long does it stall for?

Comment: edited the question - stalls for about 10 mins then fails with E503 error